# manipulate a table to use one column entries to create new columns, and count of items for each column

Tags: google-bigquery

Apologize if this question was already existing, but (as you can tell from the thread title) i had a hard time explaining the exact task

I have a table with different names, and each name could own 1 or more vehicles
My goal is to transform this in a table where, instead of having "item" and "quantity" as columns,  I have each vehicle as column header ("Car", "Boat"), and the units of each vehicle next to each person

--> starting situation

| Person | Item | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Alan | Car | 1 |
| Alan | Boat | 2 |
| Brad | Car | 3 |
| Brad | Boat | 2 |
| Charles | Boat | 3 |

---> final result

| Person | Car | Boat |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Alan | 1 | 2 |
| Brad | 3 | 2 |
| Charles | 0 | 3 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below simple approach

```
select *
from data
pivot (sum(quantity) for item in ('Car', 'Boat'))
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: thank you so much Mikhail, I completely ignored the pivot function in BQ :)